# Adwhirl + inMobi Problem in Android

Tags: android, adwhirl

I am trying to use inMobi(ver 2) through Adwhirl(2.6.3) on my Android(2.2) application.
But I am recieving an odd problem.

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Here is the stack trace:

```
03-21 21:33:39.656: VERBOSE/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457): requestactivity=AdRequest&d-deviceModel=Nexus+One&d-deviceMachineHW=Linux%28Android%3A2.6.35.7-59423-g08607d4%29&d-deviceSystemName=BASE&d-deviceSystemVersion=1.0&d-deviceName=google&d-deviceBTHW=Sat+Mar+19+08%3A15%3A44+GMT%2B02%3A00+2011&d-deviceStorageSize=InBuilt%3A196+MB%2CExt%3A3+GB&d-device-screen-density=1.5&d-device-screen-size=480X800&x-inmobi-phone-useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+2.3.3%3B+en-us%3B+Nexus+One+Build%2FGRI40%29+AppleWebKit%2F533.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F533.1&mk-siteid=ff8080812eb70f85012ecd66bc330119&u-id=173adca6177f8d35&mk-version=pr-SPEC-ATATA-20091223&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=InMobi_androidsdk%3D2.0&u-InMobi_androidwebsdkVersion=2.0&u-appBId=com.tests.mytest&u-appDNM=Pattern+Maker&u-appVer=1.1&d-localization=en_us&d-netType=&mk-banner-size=9
03-21 21:33:39.656: WARN/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457): requestactivity=AdRequest&d-deviceModel=Nexus+One&d-deviceMachineHW=Linux%28Android%3A2.6.35.7-59423-g08607d4%29&d-deviceSystemName=BASE&d-deviceSystemVersion=1.0&d-deviceName=google&d-deviceBTHW=Sat+Mar+19+08%3A15%3A44+GMT%2B02%3A00+2011&d-deviceStorageSize=InBuilt%3A196+MB%2CExt%3A3+GB&d-device-screen-density=1.5&d-device-screen-size=480X800&x-inmobi-phone-useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+2.3.3%3B+en-us%3B+Nexus+One+Build%2FGRI40%29+AppleWebKit%2F533.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F533.1&mk-siteid=ff8080812eb70f85012ecd66bc330119&u-id=173adca6177f8d35&mk-version=pr-SPEC-ATATA-20091223&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=InMobi_androidsdk%3D2.0&u-InMobi_androidwebsdkVersion=2.0&u-appBId=com.tests.mytest&u-appDNM=Pattern+Maker&u-appVer=1.1&d-localization=en_us&d-netType=&mk-banner-size=9
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457): Exception retrieving ad
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457): com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.net.ConnectionException: Error requesting new Ad 
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.net.RequestResponseManager.retrieveAd(RequestResponseManager.java:197)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.net.RequestResponseManager.requestAd(RequestResponseManager.java:54)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView.fetchAndDisplayAd(InMobiAdView.java:206)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView.access$4(InMobiAdView.java:179)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView$3.call(InMobiAdView.java:292)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView$3.call(InMobiAdView.java:1)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.BackgroundWorker$1.run(BackgroundWorker.java:36)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://w.sandbox.mkhoj.com/showad.asm
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.net.RequestResponseManager.retrieveAd(RequestResponseManager.java:157)
03-21 21:33:41.576: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(30457):     ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm from the InMobi Operations team. The problem is that the latest Adwhirl release does not have the updated InMobi Adapters. Can you try with the following versions of the Adwhirl Adapter and the InMobi SDK?

Updated InMobi Android SDK: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16117/InMobi_Android_SDK_Rel_v2.3.zip Update Adwhirl Adapters:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30899852/InMobiAdapter.java – This is for the Source version of Adwhirl SDK http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30899852/adWhirl/AdWhirlSDK_Android_3.0.0.jar – This is for developers using the Compiled version of the Adwhirl SDK (has the adapters of other ad networks which come by default with the Source SDK)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, have you requested the Internet permission ?

Comment: Yes, I have.  My application is already working successfully with Admob through Adwhirl. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

InMobi adapter that is part of the Adwhirl SDK is not compatible with InMobi SDK version 2.0

Please star the open issues (looks like some are repeated) here:

http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/issues/detail?id=176
http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/issues/detail?id=186
http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/issues/detail?id=187